Sealant recommendation for double hung windows
I have these type of windows throughout the house. On several I can hear outside noise louder than other windows and they feel cooler as well. I was wondering what kind of sealant I could use to fill in the gaps.




Which gaps would those be? Do you intend to remove your interior casing to access framing? Please revise to make your plan and question more clear.

I was referring to the gap between the window frame and trim. I'm not sure that is the source of the noise and air flow but I don't see any other gaps.

That's absolutely not where you'd seal against airflow. You're also likely to make a nasty mess of your trim.

Neither of those if you are talking about the joints between the sash and frame and between the two sashes. Which seems likely.
Those can be sealed (without ruining the window and making it unopenable when summer comes) by using removable caulking (a weird but effective product, which can in fact be removed with relative ease when you want to use the window again.)
An alternative that is also seasonally removable and which also adds an extra layer of trapped air is to use a shrink-film window insulating kit, and attach it to the edge of the frame nearest the wall (away from the window itself) so that it catches the leaks that may be present in the frame itself as well as those between sash and frame.
The caulking you show would be used on the outside between the fixed parts of the frame and the siding (but NOT on the bottom - have to let any water that gets in drain away) and spray foam is risky around a double-hung window, as depending on design details, you may block the counterbalance system and prevent the window from opening.

I found DAP Seal N Peal Removable Caulking on Amazon. That sounds like what you recommend using.
